# Doxygen does not properly determine return type

Tags: c++, doxygen, preprocessor-directive

I have this code:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
int
#else
void
#endif
init_numpy()
{
    import_array();
}
```

This is not pretty, but that is not the issue I have (the reason for this code is discussed here https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-December/054357.html).

The issue I have is that if I add a doxygen comment above like this:

```
/*! \brief some function
*
*/
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
...
```

Doxygen assumes that this method has return type void. Which is of course not true in general.

#### Question

Is there a way I can get the correct documentation, namely that the return type depends on the Python version used. I don't mind, if the code above is changed a bit (as long as the functionality is the same of course).

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. With 1.8.11 I don't have a problem. See also the tags about preprocessing in the Doxyfile

Comment: The doxygen-wizard says I am using 1.8.11. And what do you mean by not having a problem? Is is showing something like (int/void) in your generated documentation?

Comment: In my documentation I see either int or void depending on the setting of PY_MAJOR_VERSION in the PREDEFINED item of the Doxyfile. The possibility "int/void" will never be shown as this is contradicting the code, this can only be achieved in a description.

Answer (score 1):

You can just hardcode the return type into the comment. It will have the tag [return] (I think) and just have the types it could be (int/void), then include the reason why in the description.

Comment: I couldn't find what you are describing. Here (https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdreturn) it says that you can only add a description, not the type.

Comment: Add @return to the doxygen comment and then describe what is returning. Doxygen should then include this in the documentation.

Comment: But this only adds a description in the detailed section. In the overview of all methods it still says void instead of something like (int/void).

Comment: Thats probably as good as you are going to get unfortunately. This is an exceedingly rare and generally unadvised usage of preprocessor statements so I wouldn't expect it to pick it up. You could flip the statement around if you want it to show int as the return type. Such as #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3 void  #else int .